# C# Datagridview WinForms вывод объекта в объекте?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Возможно ли вывести в таблицу сложный объект **Person** со следующими столбцами:

**Person.Name | Person.Finance.BankName | Person.Finance.Balance**

```
    class Person
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public FinanceData Finance {get;set;}
    }
    class FinanceData 
    {
        public string BankName {get;set;}
        public double Balance {get;set;}
        //Кстати, если в Balance хранятся деньги, то ни в коем случае нельзя 
        //использовать тип double. Только decimal.
    }
```

Можно ли это вывести в таблицу без написания класса обертки? Если возможно, то как это сделать?

Comment: `dataGridView.Rows.Add(persom.Name, person.Finance.BankName, person.Finance.Balance);` - так?

Comment: Вы хотите сделать это с помощью привязки данных?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да желательно именно через неё.

Comment: Кстати, если в `Balance` хранятся деньги, то ни в коем случае нельзя использовать тип `double`. Только `decimal`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это тестовый пример, но спасибо, на будущее полезно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это с привязкой

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>() {
            new Person(){
                 Name = "Абраах",
                 Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 3.1, BankName = "asd" }
            },
            new Person(){
                 Name = "Ибрагим",
                 Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 5.6, BankName = "я" }
            },
            new Person(){
                 Name = "Придурок",
                 Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 3.3, BankName = "gfds" }
            }
        };

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); bs.DataSource = serializePeople(people);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

    private DataTable serializePeople(List<Person> people)
    {


        DataTable returnTable = new DataTable("Table");
        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FinanceBalance"));
        returnTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FinanceBankName"));
        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            returnTable.AcceptChanges();
            DataRow row = returnTable.NewRow();
            row[0] = person.Name;
            row[1] = person.Finance.Balance.ToString();
            row[2] = person.Finance.BankName;

            returnTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return returnTable;
    }
```

Comment: Сомнительное решение. Оно, конечно рабочее, но при изменении данных в гриде это не будет отражаться в исходной коллекции. То есть суть привязки данных нарушена. Хотя, если автора вопроса это устраивает...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov предложите лучше, выберу ваше решение верным

Comment: @XXX - собственно, лучшего решения и нет. Разве что вместо DataTable использовать типизированную коллекцию с классом-оберткой, что вы и писали в вопросе. Впрочем, это соответствует современным канонам проектирования: в слое бизнес-логики - одна модель, в слое GUI - модель представления (view model, та самая обертка). PS: можно еще извратиться и в событиях грида на лету подменять данные, но я так прикинул: возни много, код получается страшный и привязка данных опять же нарушена.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov бизнес логика обычно разделяется на классы которые непостредственно на низком уровне работают с БД (данными) и на `TDO` на более верхнем уровне, которые формируются из моделей нижнего уровнял для корректной работы сервисов

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>() {
                new Person(){
                     Name = "Абраах",
                     Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 3.1, BankName = "asd" }
                },
                new Person(){
                     Name = "Ибрагим",
                     Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 5.6, BankName = "я" }
                },
                new Person(){
                     Name = "Придурок",
                     Finance = new FinanceData() { Balance = 3.3, BankName = "gfds" }
                }
            };

            people.ForEach(p => { dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.Name, p.Finance.Balance.ToString(), p.Finance.BankName); });
```